# Sum of Squares Function series

Tags: calculus

i read in one the paper that 
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } r_2(k) 2^{-k t}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{2 \pi }{t \log (2)}-\frac{\pi  \left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi  (t \log (2)+8 i \pi  n)}{t \log (16)}\right)+\cot \left(\frac{\pi  (t \log (2)+8 i \pi  n)}{4 t \log (2)}\right)-2\right)}{t \log (2)}\right)-\frac{\pi }{t \log (2)}+1$$

I try using the voronoi formula but it seem do not work

Comment: What is $r_2(k)$? Please include definitions and perhaps show what you've tried.

Comment: Given the title, I'm guessing it's the number of ways of writing $k$ as a sum of 2 squares, but antonio should include the definition in the body of the question. It would also be nice to include bibliographic details on the paper.

Comment: Are you still here, antonio?

Comment: Hi Gerry  i reference the following page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html to clarify the subjects sorry for my bad english